# Windows 10 only boots with Disk in Drive - "Insert Proper Boot Device..."

Tags: windows, boot

I had Windows 8.1 installed on my SSD.

I tried to install Windows 10 yesterday with an USB Stick and eveything went okay.

When the Installation was done, I got the message

> "Insert proper Boot device...".

When I installed it again with a DVD,

> "Press a key to boot from CD..."

Showed up and after that, Windows 10 booted normally.

But after I remove the disk from my drive, the first message pops up again.

I can only boot Windows 10 when the Installation Disk in in my drive!

I already tried probably everything:

- bootrec /FixMbr /FixOs /ScanOs /RebuildBcd
- bootsect /nt60 ALL /force
- recovering BCD/MBR with EasyBCD
- Changing the Partitionsystem to GPT...
- Changing the Boot Order/unplug HDD

My Partitions are set up like this:

[image: Link]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Disable everything in the boot order except for the SSD on which Windows is installed. If the message still pops up, then there is something wrong either with the ISO or with the way you made the bootable USB.

Comment: I already did that.  I made the USB stick and the ISO separately and both are different versions